# Should I dispose IRandomAccessStream or underlying MemoryStream?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, uwp, dispose

which of following is correct?

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   var randomAccessStream = memoryStream.AsRandomAccessStream();
   process(randomAccessStream);
}
```

or

```
using (var randomAccessStream = new MemoryStream().AsRandomAccessStream())
{
   process(randomAccessStream);
}
```

I know I can use  `Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();` directly but I'm curious anyways. Ideally, MSDN article with explanation would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code of AsRandomAccessStream extensions method you don't need to dispose underlying stream.

You can easily find assembly `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll` on your disk and have a look on its source code using any decompiler (e.g. JetBrains dotPeek).

AsRandomAccessStream method creates an instance of `NetFxToWinRtStreamAdapter` class which implements `IDisposable` in an appropriate way:

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
  Stream managedStream = this.managedStream;
  if (managedStream == null)
    return;
  this.managedStream = (Stream) null;
  if (this.leaveUnderlyingStreamOpen) //this flag is equal to false.
    return;
  managedStream.Dispose();
}
```